# How to Run Testcomplete from command line

Tags: automated-tests, testcomplete

I have a project in test complete that contains only Test scripts no keyword testing.
When i run my main script from command line it gives compiler error "file missing". I want to catch this error in cmd and close test complete.

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 11\Bin\TestComplete.exe" "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\project\TestProject1\BLABLABLA" /r /p:projectname /u:Scriptname /rt:MainScriptRoutine /run /exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that TestComplete is not just stopped with the error message displayed during your night tests, you can run it with the **/SilentMode** command-line parameter. In this case, TestComplete will not show any GUI dialogs and messages.